# Can I get id of the related object without loading the related object?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets say we have User and Article with oneToMany relationship.

```
$article = $em->getRepository('Article')->find($articleid);
```

Now this $article has a user_id field. If I access it like so:

```
$article->getUser()->getId();
```

It lazy loads the related user object, when I simply need to get the user_id field in database and lazy loading is not necessary.

$article->getUserId() does not work, since there is no such method.

Any ideas how to get that id without loading related user?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is wondering, it appears that this issue is fixed in Doctrine version 2.2